# Getting attribute using XPath and giving inner text using value attribute

Tags: xml, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Given an XML structure like so:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>    
            <th><div data-col="0">First Name</div></th>
            <th><div data-col="1">Last Name</div></th>
            <th><div data-col="2">Age</div></th>
            <th><div data-col="3">Id</div></th>
            <th><div data-col="4">City</div></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-row="0">
            <td data-col="0"><div>Ivan</div></td>
            <td data-col="1"><div>Ivanov</div></td>
            <td data-col="2"><div>35</div></td>
            <td data-col="3"><div>EFF-12218</div></td>
            <td data-col="4"><div>London</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

1. How could I get the value of `data-col` (where `text = 'id'`), for the
   first element?
2. How could I get the value of text in this cell
   (`'EFF-12218'`) using found value of `data-col` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How could I get the value of data-col (where text = 'id'), for the first element?

`String colNumber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Id']")).getAttribute("data-col");`

2. And how could I get the value of text in this cell ('EFF-12218') using found value of data-col ?

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-col='" + colNumber + "']")).getText();`

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the *value* of **data-col** where *text* is `id` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table/thead//th/div[text()='Id']").get_attribute("data-col"))
  ```

Ideally, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following solution:

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table/thead//th/div[contains(., 'Id')]"))).get_attribute("data-col"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

To retrieve the *value* **EFF-12218** with respect to `data-col="3"` you can use the following solution:

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  data-col = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table//th//div[text()='Id']").get_attribute("data-col")
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table//tbody/tr//td[@data-col='"+ data-col +"']/div").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```

Ideally, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following solution:

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  data-col = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table//th//div[contains(., 'Id')]"))).get_attribute("data-col")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table//tbody/tr//td[@data-col='"+ data-col +"']/div"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```

Comment: Very thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

To use the value of the attribute `data-col` as an index to the children of the `<tbody>` element, use this XPath-1.0 expression

```
//tbody/tr/td[@data-col=//thead/tr/th[div/text()='Id']/div/@data-col]
```

Its result is

> EFF-12218

as expected.
The answer to your first question is, by the way, the following

```
//thead/tr/th[div/text()='Id']/div/@data-col
```

which is a part of the second question.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below response it will help you to get text of any cell. you have to just change value of row and column in xpath:

```
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 // to Get Text of ID( you can store into array/arraylist
// By Changing the row column value in xpath //tbody/tr[row]/td[column]) you can get 
   //data of any cell of table
List<WebElement> id_elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[4]"));
int noOfRow= id_elements.size();
for(int i=0; i<=noOfRow;i++) {
    String id = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[4]")).getText();
    System.out.println(id);
    }
```

Hope it gives you idea!